# eval() and run() in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm referring to **Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial** given by the tensorflow. I have a problem in [Train and Evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#train-and-evaluate-the-model) part of that tutorial. There they have given a sample code as follows.

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv),reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                       y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

So in these code segment they have used `accuracy.eval()` at one time. And other time `train_step.run()`. As I know of both of them are tensor variables.

And in some cases, I have seen like

```
sess.run(variable, feed_dict)
```

So my question is what are the differences between these 3 implementations. And how can I know what to use when..?

Thank You!!

Comment: `eval` and `run` are both aliases that redirect to `sess.run`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have only one default session, they are basically the same.

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2351:

> op.run() is a shortcut for calling tf.get_default_session().run(op)

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L691:

> t.eval() is a shortcut for calling tf.get_default_session().run(t)

Difference between Tensor and Operation:

Tensor: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor

Operation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation

> Note: the Tensor class will be replaced by Output in the future. Currently these two are aliases for each other.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in Operations vs. Tensors. Operations use run() and Tensors use eval().

There seems to be a reference to this question in TensorFlow FAQ: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#running_a_tensorflow_computation

The section addresses the following question: What is the difference between Session.run() and Tensor.eval()?