# Cannot create custom classifier in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

So far here is what I've done:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dists_next_error = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
dists_center_error = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
pts_count = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
ideal_polygon = tf.Variable(0.)

cost = tf.square(dists_next_error)      \
        + tf.square(dists_center_error) \
        + tf.square(pts_count - ideal_polygon)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.05).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

hund_zeros = tf.zeros([100])
hund_ones = tf.ones([100])

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
        dists_next_error: hund_zeros,
        dists_center_error: hund_zeros,
        pts_count: hund_ones})

print(cost.eval(feed_dict={
        dists_next_error: 0.,
        dists_center_error: 0.,
        pts_count: 6.}))         #it should output 0 or close to it.
```

---

The problem is in

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
        dists_next_error: hund_zeros,
        dists_center_error: hund_zeros,
        pts_count: hund_ones})
```

in the `pts_count` line more precisely, where it says:

> TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.

But I see no tensors  in `pts_count` so I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensor can't be used as feed values (this you knew); tf.ones(), tf.zeros create `Tensors`. So,

```
hund_zeros = tf.zeros([100])
hund_ones = tf.ones([100])
```

are just Tensors.

What you want to do is send in some actual numbers (this was you're intention, it seems). You could use:

- numpy: `np.ones([100])` and `np.zeros([100])`,
- or use `hund_zeros, hund_ones = sess.run([hund_zeros, hund_ones])`
- use `Tensor.eval()` method

refer to the answers here to learn more about [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987466/eval-and-run-in-tensorflow)

Below is the code you provided changed using `with` context manager that runs:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dists_next_error = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
dists_center_error = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
pts_count = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
ideal_polygon = tf.Variable(0.)

cost = tf.square(dists_next_error)      \
        + tf.square(dists_center_error) \
        + tf.square(pts_count - ideal_polygon)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.05).minimize(cost)


hund_zeros = tf.zeros([100])
hund_ones = tf.ones([100])

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session()  as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # run graphs to get some constants
    hund_zeros, hund_ones = sess.run([hund_zeros, hund_ones])

    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
            dists_next_error: hund_zeros,
            dists_center_error: hund_zeros,
            pts_count: hund_ones})

    print(cost.eval(feed_dict={
            dists_next_error: 0.,
            dists_center_error: 0.,
            pts_count: 6.}))
```

Start with this.