# Eval Variable in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, eval

From the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990824/1691873), I known that `Tensor.eval()` is equalent to `tf.get_default_session().run(t)`, but When I eval a tensor, I met errors. The code below emit errors if line marked by 1 is omitted, Why? Then I tried to call `W.initializer`'s `eval()` method to replace `run()`,  but the `W.initializer` has no `eval()` method and `tf.constant`(as a operation) do has one, Why?

```
def test_eval():
    W = tf.constant(10)
    with tf.Session():
        print(W.eval())         # 10


def test_eval_Variable():
    W = tf.Variable(10)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(W.initializer))  # None <--- 1.
        print(W.eval())                 # 10


def test_eval_Variable_all():
    W = tf.Variable(10)
    with tf.Session():
        print(W.initializer.eval())  # error: object has no attribute 'eval'
        print(W.eval())
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** The code below emit errors if line

`sess.run(W.initializer)`

is omitted

Answer: As the error says

`FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value`

You are trying to evaluate an **uninitialized variable**. So, you need to **initialize it**. There are best ways than calling
`sess.run(W.initializer)` anyways.

**2.** Then I tried to call `W.initializer's eval()` method to replace `run()`, but the `W.initializer` has no `eval()` method and `tf.constant` (as a operation) do has one, Why?

Answer: `eval()` is a function of operations, tensors but not initializers. It's right that the `initializer` doesn't have the `eval()` function.

**What you should do?**

You should use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` to initialize your variables.

```
def initialize_properly():
    W = tf.Variable(10)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #This way
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        print(W.eval()) 
        print(sess.run(W))
```

Comment: I think [initializers are operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#initializer), why they can't  be evaluated?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but to be honest, evaluate an initializer doesn't make sense to me.